# Is there a way of merging two or more data extensions in Exact Target?

Tags: dataextensions, merge

We want to create a master data extension which keeps data from all the extensions. As we think, keeping in one extension will help in running filters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a [Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

```
select
emailAddress
from DataExtension1
union
select
emailaddress
from DataExtension2

/* add additional unions here */

/* target: MasterDataExtension */
/* action: update */
```