# Compliance bcc in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to add a compliance bcc email to every email job created in marketing cloud? There is a functionality in sales cloud - Compliance bcc email, I'm looking for the same in marketing cloud but for every email job.
for example when an email job is created to send an email to 2000 contacts one copy of that email also goes to our compliance email.
we tried using the bcc functionality but it didn't work as desired. when 1 email was bcc'd in an email job that was to be send to 12000 contacts, the bcc'd email address received that email 12000 times. we need it to be delivered to the bcc'd email address just once.
Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an ideal way but you can add that email address to your data extension that has the audience.

Comment: right, so that would mean adding it every time a new data extension is created?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add manually in Contact Builder, you can put that email address in a data extension having a field for primary key and email address, named A and then you have B as an audience.

Now, you can execute the SQL mentioned here: [Is there a way of merging two or more data extensions in Exact Target?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132855/is-there-a-way-of-merging-two-or-more-data-extensions-in-exact-target)

select *
from A
union
select *
from B

Yet, you need to consider the fact that if your sendable data extension has some extra non-nullable fields, SQL cannot be executed.